# how to prove that the the unitary group SUn(q) is generated by transvections?

Tags: finite-groups

how to prove the simplicity of unitary group over finite fields

Comment: The question you ask in the body is not the same as the question you ask in the title.  Please fix this.

Answer (score 1):

A proof that special unitary groups over a field $F$ are generated by transvections -- except when $n = 3$ and $\# F = 4$ in which case the result is not true -- is given in [Larry Grove's text](http://books.google.com/books?id=QuxiDFCLAP4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Larry+Grove,+Classical+Groups&source=bl&ots=_dsKggXFFF&sig=0I9CfQsowF_W3WuRggbIF289YLo&hl=en&ei=QW3yTJ-BFYXGlQenjaGwDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false): see Theorem 11.15 on page 104.

The simplicity of the **projective** special unitary group $PSU(V)$ -- except when $(\operatorname{dim} V, \# F)$ is one of $(2,4)$, $(2,9)$ and $(3,4)$ in which cases the result is not true -- is Theorem 11.26 on page 108 of Grove's text.